# How to subscribe to a Q&A?

Tags: support

I can't seem to find a way to subscribe to a Q&A to get notified about new answers. I know I can "favorite" a question but that doesn't notify me of updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the bottom of each question, there is a question feed icon to subscribe to a question.

[image]

As the question author, you can also select "☑ Notify [email address] daily of any new answers".

Comment: thanks a bunch, I'll try that