# What about subscribing for a question?

Tags: support

I found a discussion [here](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/133/4471) but it is only for the OPs; what about someone who wants to get notified without directly interacting in the topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing we've got is the favourites link next to each question (the star in the below image)

[image]

After clicking one of those for a question, you just need to visit the favourites tabs in your profile to see it

[image]

Comment: Ohh, i was thinking about the inbox with red circle to notify me on an answer or comment. Is it possible ?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge it's not, favourites are as far as SE go with being reminded about specific questions